# Using user agent against fake posts to sql

Tags: mysql, user-agent

I have an SQL database to which a physical device sends data by visiting a php POST page. What I would like to know is if filtering the user agent, making my own, say "Foo" user agent and then adding an if statement to the PHP to continue in the script only if the user agent is "Foo".
Not as a security measure, but to say prevent someone from entering the data by hand. Is this a viable solution?

Comment: There's nothing stopping someone from configuring his browser to send `Foo` as the user agent.

Comment: They can also use `curl -A Foo`